# how to round a textbox output to a whole number in .net

Tags: .net, rounding

I have tried to have a whole number show up in txtMCQresult textbox from the result of a calculation done in a different textbox but unable to find a way.

```
Private Sub btnEnterMCQ_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEnterMCQ.Click

      txtMCQresult.Text = MidpointRounding(Integer.Parse(txtMCQ.Text) / 35 * 20)
      txtMCQresult.Enabled = True

End Sub
```

Comment: So what is the problem you are having? The rounding, or getting it to show up?

Comment: Both,  the calculations work perfectly but Id rather the answer rounded up to a whole number instead of 14.7584937349393 for example

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub btnEnterMCQ_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEnterMCQ.Click

      txtMCQresult.text = Math.Round((Integer.Parse(txtMCQ.Text) / 35 * 20), 1, MidpointRounding.ToEven)
      txtMCQresult.Enabled = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use

txtMCQresult.text = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(xtMCQ.Text), 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven);

Comment: I am only new to vb so I not the best at putting this code in, this is my code ,  
        If IsNumeric(txtMCQ.Text) Then
            If txtMCQ.Text < 36 Then
                txtMCQresult.Text = (Integer.Parse(txtMCQ.Text) / 35 * 20)
                txtMCQresult. Enabled = True     
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Value incorrect, please enter value less than 36")
                txtMCQresult.Enabled = False
                txtMCQ.Clear()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

Comment: Hi Michelle ,



You put my code like 



If IsNumeric(txtMCQ.Text)
 Then 
If txtMCQ.Text < 36 
Then 
//my Code 
txtMCQresult.text = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(txtMCQ.Text / 35 * 20), 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
txtMCQresult. Enabled = True 
Else 
MessageBox.Show("Value incorrect, please enter value less than 36") txtMCQresult.Enabled = False 
txtMCQ.Clear()
End If 
End If

Answer (score 0):

Put Pramod's code after 
If txtMCQ.TEXT <36 then

txtMCQresult.Text = "Pramod's code"